# Overflow on question/answer signatures

Tags: bug

As you can see, the bronze badges section in the signature exceeds the its own area and is overflowed. You may wanna check the *div.user-info*

Original question where I noticed this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355543/pass-argument-to-a-composite-component-action-attribute)

[image]

Comment: Surprising- Clicking into this, I expected the screen shot to be of Jon Skeet's user card.